# Google Sign In not working in Release mode or TestFlight, works in Debug mode *iOS*

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app is using Firebase for authentication, and it works fine with phone auth and google sign in on debug mode locally. But, when I run it locally in release mode or on Apple TestFlight, the google sign in does not work. Phone auth works fine in release and TestFlight, but I am not being prompted at all to choose a google account. When I click my sign in with google button nothing happens.

My app is signed with the correct Developer account
Google Sign In is assigned to the same developer account
My app's CFBundleURLSchemes is correctly set in Info.plist
GoogleService-Info.plist is assigned to Runner and has been added to the project, not sure if this matters but this file is in my system's Downloads folder, then I added it to Runner in Xcode... does this file need to be in my project's directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected... should of tried this before posting but maybe this will help someone else.

GoogleService-Info.plist needs to be in project-dir/ios/Runner/

Then add it in Xcode, select Add file to Runner, make sure the file's target is Runner.

That got it working in release mode running locally, and on TestFlight.